# If status change refresh <div> once, after restart setInterval timer

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, marquee

I want to do this with status == 1, refresh div tag once after 6 second to launch the marquee element. If status == 0, the marquee disappears from the page. After minute restart Interval again do wait if status again change to one.

I'm using now this code, but this code not working as I need.

**First page: marquee.php**

```
<?php 
$link = mysqli_connect("localhost", "username", "password", "database"); 
$database = "SELECT * FROM alerts ORDER BY id DESC"; $result = mysqli_query($link, $database);

date_default_timezone_set("Europe/Tallinn");
$time = date("d.m.Y H:i:s");
$real_timestamp = strtotime($time);

$row = mysqli_fetch_array($result);
    $db_time = $row['timestamp'];
    $status = $row['status'];
    $db_timestamp = strtotime($db_time);
    $alarmtime = $db_timestamp + 55;

if(($status == 'Active')&&($alarmtime > $real_timestamp)){ ?>

<marquee behavior="slide" direction="left" scrollamount="3" loop=1>Some information</marquee>

<?php } ?>
```

**Second page: index.php**

```
<html>
    <head>
       <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-4">
       <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
       <script>
           function myFn(){
              $('#marquee').load('marquee.php');} 
           var myTimer = setInterval(myFn, 6000); 
              clearInterval(myTimer);
              myTimer = setInterval(myFn, 60000);
       </script>
       <div id="marquee"></div>
    </body>
</html>
```